# Error inflating class EmojiPalettesView in LatinIME(AOSP)

Tags: java, android, android-source

I checked out [Google LatinIME](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/). Then I imported the `java` folder into `Android Studio`.

I ran it, set it up (I chose a keyboard in the phone settings, I chose a language layout) 
But during testing (by focusing on `edittext`) the `application` crashes with an error:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Binary XML
>   file line #21: Error inflating class
>   com.android.inputmethod.keyboard.emoji.EmojiPalettesView

Here is full StackTrace:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.android.inputmethod.latin, PID: 19332
>                                                      android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Binary XML
>   file line #21: Error inflating class
>   com.android.inputmethod.keyboard.emoji.EmojiPalettesView
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>                                                          at com.android.inputmethod.keyboard.KeyboardSwitcher.onCreateInputView(KeyboardSwitcher.java:464)
>                                                          at com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME.onCreateInputView(LatinIME.java:752)
>                                                          at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.updateInputViewShown(InputMethodService.java:1117)
>                                                          at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.showWindowInner(InputMethodService.java:1473)
>                                                          at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.showWindow(InputMethodService.java:1447)
>                                                          at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService$InputMethodImpl.showSoftInput(InputMethodService.java:437)
>                                                          at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.executeMessage(IInputMethodWrapper.java:203)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:37)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
>                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error
>   inflating class
>   com.android.inputmethod.keyboard.emoji.EmojiPalettesView
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:941)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                                                          at com.android.inputmethod.keyboard.KeyboardSwitcher.onCreateInputView(KeyboardSwitcher.java:464)

**Question:**
Help me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: by "importing" you mean you added files as module or you simply copied and pasted classes in java folder?
if you copied them 'com.android.inputmethod.keyboard.emoji.EmojiPalettesView' is not a correct path for that class

Comment: I checked out through git, not copied/pasted

Comment: Probably, another exception is causing this exception. Please, try to capture and log any exception and then paste here the full stack trace.

Comment: @MiguelKVidal, The fact is that I tried other projects besides this library, but I received the same error from them. This is an [Indic-Keyboard](https://github.com/smc/Indic-Keyboard) and so on.

Comment: did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Getting same error @NoName did u mange to solve it?